# Which is the fastest tokenization function in Python 3?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nltk, tokenize, textblob

In Python 3, we can use re.compile(), nltk.tokenize() and TextBlob.words() to tokenize a given text. I think there may be other methods too, but I am unaware of them.

Which of these methods or other unmentioned methods tokenizes a given text the fastest?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm sure you can just benchmark these methods and see for yourself which is fastest.

Comment: Could you tell me how to benchmarks these methods? Are you suggesting me to capture the timestamp before and after tokenizing a sample text and calculate their difference, and compare how each method did? Or is this method not reliable, and if so, is there another method to compare their performance?

Comment: Put each one in a 10,000x for loop and see how long they take.

Comment: @ShreyasYakhob: yes, do just that. Only to minimize the effect of overhead/measuring errors, time how long does it take to do a few thousand iterations, as CAustin suggests.

Answer (score 2):

After calculating the difference in the timestamps between the start and end of each tokenize function, I have come to the following observation:

1) Regex operation is the fastest. The code is as follows:

```
import re
WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')
def regTokenize(text):
    words = WORD.findall(text)
    return words
```

The time taken for tokenizing 100,000 simple, one-lined strings is 0.843757 seconds.

2) NLTK word_tokenize(text) is second. The code is as follows:

```
import nltk
def nltkTokenize(text):
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    return words
```

The time taken for tokenizing 100,000 simple, one-lined strings is 18.869182 seconds.

3) TextBlob.words is the slowest. The code is as follows:

```
from textblob import TextBlob as tb
def blobTokenize(text):
    words = tb(text).words
    return words
```

The time taken for tokenizing 100,000 simple, one-lined strings is 34.310102 seconds.

- Regex operation is extremely fast.
- However, NLTK also tokenizes characters, so it returns a bigger list.
- TextBlob is almost twice as slow as NLTK, but stores only the words from the 
  tokenized list.

If anybody else was wondering the same thing, here is the answer.

Comment: Generally, the slower functions do more, and if you need that "more" you can't really compromise because something simpler would be faster. If crude regex tokenization is sufficient for your particular application (and the orthographic conventions of the language(s) you are processing), more power to you.

Comment: I don't know if flashtext is still faster than regex in certain operations as it claims. Just found out today. 
https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext

It hasn't been updated since May 3rd. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: does anyone have a reference as to the "result" of using all these tokenizers and their difference in accuracy?